# Show First 5 value in an array that has the most duplicates values

Tags: php, arrays

I want to show first five array value who has most duplicate value like in tags we show the popular tags like that now what i have done till now is i am getting all tags from database as you can see below

```
SMS Gateway,sms service,bulk sms,bulk sms, Courier Management Software Development, Customised software solutions, domain registration, Ecommerce website designing company, matrimony website developer, seo tutorials bhopal, Web-site designing, redesigning, updationsSMS Gateway,sms service,bulk sms
```

and after that exploding it into array and printing it in li like below

```
 $tag = explode(",", $tags);

  $tagsss = array_count_values($tag);

    foreach($tagsss as $key => $value) {
      echo "<li>$key ( $value )</li>";
    }
```

and the result is showing like this

```
SMS Gateway ( 1 )sms service ( 2 )bulk sms ( 3 ) Courier Management Software Development ( 1 ) Customised software solutions ( 1 ) domain registration ( 1 ) Ecommerce website designing company ( 1 ) matrimony website developer ( 1 ) seo tutorials bhopal ( 1 ) Web-site designing ( 1 ) redesigning ( 1 ) updationsSMS Gateway ( 1 )
```

Now in all this entry i just want to show first five value who have the most duplicate value just like popular tags

Comment: `arsort($tagsss); $tagsss = array_slice($tagsss, 0, 5);`

Comment: show youe expected output

Comment: Thanks a lot @splash58 this is exactly what i want

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using PHP function I'll get those tags from MySQL only from query like as

```
SELECT CONCAT( tag_name,  " ", COUNT( tag_name ) ) AS tags
FROM tags_table
GROUP BY tag_name
ORDER BY COUNT( tag_name ) DESC 
LIMIT 5
```